# Python grep word and show line before this word

Tags: python, for-loop, grep

i should find some line. I wrote script. I have a file, where i should find line `duke`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

for line in open('test.txt'):
    if 'duke' in line:
        print(line)
```

Everything is ok. But how can i see 2 lines before this result ?

In grep it was `grep -B 2 "duke" test.txt`. How can i do the same in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a buffer with N preceding lines (in this case, N=2). Example:

```
N=2
buffer = []
for line in open('test.txt'):
    buffer.append(line)
    if len(buffer) > N:
        buffer.pop(0)
    if 'duke' in line:
        print(buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `deque` with a fixed size of 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
from collections import deque

queue = deque(maxlen=2)

for line in open('test.txt'):
    if 'duke' in line:
        print(list(queue))
    queue.append(line)
```

Comment: `grep -B 2` prints two preceding lines **plus** the current line, to achieve this you should put `queue.append(line)` before `if` and increase `maxlen` to 3, or just add `print(line)` after `print(list(queue))`.

Comment: I think adjusting the numbers and rearranging logic is a nice homework ;)